# Show $\sup_\limits{n\in\omega}\prod_\limits{i\in n}2=\aleph_{0}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I would appreciate help showing:

$$\sup_{n\in\omega} \prod_{i\in n} 2$$

I think $\prod_\limits{i\in n}2=2^n$. If this is correct, then I am stuck on what $\sup_\limits{n\in\omega}2^{n}$ is.

To the extent that $\omega$ is the $\sup$ of the natural numbers, then it would be $2^\omega$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$. But I don't think this is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Notice this difference: $$\sup_{n\in\omega} \Pi_{i\in n} 2 $$ $$\text{versus}$$ $$ \sup_{n\in\omega} \prod_{i\in n} 2$$ The latter is the right way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks- I was looking for a comparable to copy, but was in a bit of a rush yesterday. With regards,

Comment: A place to look for that is what you get if you google "latex symbols". $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sup_{n\in\omega} 2^n = \omega$$

It is obvious that the supremum could not be any finite number (there is always a power of two greater than it).

$\omega$ is greater than every $2^n$, and is the smallest infinite ordinal.

Therefore, it is the supremum.

Comment: As stated, the problem  is about cardinal numbers.

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\omega=\aleph_0$

Comment: Even though technically alepa_1 = omega_1, the sup of numbers < aleph_1 is less than the sup of numbers < omega_1 because of the context of the numbers.

Comment: @WilliamElliot 1. replace "numbers" with "ordinals" and you have two equal ordinals; 2. this is about $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$, not $\omega_1$ and $\aleph_1$.